# Understanding algorithm to show $(x+\partial_x)e^{-x^2/2}=0$ using python?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, gaussian

I am given the following Python code which is supposed to verify numerically that

$$(\partial_x + x)e^{-x^2/2}=0.$$

The algorithm does this, by transforming everything into a Fourier basis and then verifying it using the Fourier transform. However, I have some difficulties understanding the mathematical basis of this algorithm. In short, my question is:

When the final result is computed as `np.dot( D, yl )`, what is that actually in mathematical terms that we are computing here?

```
 import numpy as np

 ## non-normalized gaussian with sigma=1
 def gauss( x ):
return np.exp( -x**2 / 2 )

  ## interval on which the gaussian is evaluated
 L = 10
 ## number of sampling points
 N = 21
 ## sample rate
 dl = L / N
 ## highest frequency detectable
 kmax= 1 / ( 2 * dl )

 ## array of x values
 xl = np.linspace( -L/2, L/2, N )
 ## array of k values
 kl = np.linspace( -kmax, kmax, N )

 ## matrix of exponents
## the Fourier transform is defined via sum f * exp( -2 pi j k x)
  ## i.e. the 2 pi is in the exponent
 ## normalization is sqrt(N) where n is the number of sampling points
 ## this definition makes it forward-backward symmetric
 ## "outer" also exists in Matlab and basically does the same
exponent = np.outer( -1j * 2 * np.pi * kl, xl ) 
## linear operator for the standard Fourier transformation
 A = np.exp( exponent ) / np.sqrt( N )

 ## nth derivative is given via partial integration as  ( 2 pi j k)^n f(k)
 ## every row needs to be multiplied by the according k
 B = np.array( [ 1j * 2 * np.pi * kk * An for kk, An in zip( kl, A ) ] )

 ## for the part with the linear term, every column needs to be multiplied
## by the according x or--as here---every row is multiplied element 
 ## wise with the x-vector
C = np.array( [ xl * An for An in  A ] )

 ## thats the according linear operator
 D = B + C

 ## the gaussian
 yl = gauss( xl )

 ## the transformation with the linear operator
 print(  np.dot( D, yl ).round( decimals=9 ) ) 
## ...results in a zero-vector, as expected
```

Comment: Theoretrically, taking the fourier transform leaves you with exactly the same equation (modulo some constants depending on the fourier transform), so why bother...?

Comment: @CalvinKhor sorry, the question is just that I want to understand exactly what this algorithm does because I want to use its output in some other scenarios.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, if you follow every line (and all the comments) prior to the `print(...)` line. Is your question about the meaning of `np.dot(...)`...? Or are you (and I guess this is more likely) unsure what `D` is?

Comment: I do understand what the code does, but I am not really sure I understand the mathematical basis for what is happening here. I would like to see someone explaining to me the mathematics behind this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

> `print(  np.dot( D, yl ).round( decimals=9 ) )`

calculates the integrals of the Fourier transform at set of frequencies using the rectangle integration method:
\begin{equation}
F(k) = \int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-ikx}\left(\partial_x + x\right)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\left.e^{-ikx}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right\vert^{\infty}_{-\infty} +\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(ik + x)e^{-ikx}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(ik + x)e^{-ikx}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\approx\int\limits^{5}_{-5}\left(ik + x\right)e^{-ikx}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\approx\sum\limits^{N}_{j = 0}(ik + x_j)e^{-ikx_j}\Delta{x}e^{-\frac{x^2_j}{2}}=\sum\limits^{N}_{j = 0}v^{(k)}_jf_j=(\vec{v}^{(k)}, \vec{f}),
\end{equation}
where $\Delta{x}$ is the coordinate step, $v^{(k)}_j = (ik + x_j)e^{-ikx_j}\Delta{x}$, $f_j = e^{-\frac{x^2_j}{2}}$. Since we want to calculate the following ressult vector $\vec{r}$: $r_p = F(k_p)$, we can to introduce the matrix $D$:
\begin{equation}
D =
\begin{pmatrix}
(\vec{v}^{(k_0)})^{\intercal}\\
(\vec{v}^{(k_1)})^{\intercal}\\
\vdots\\
(\vec{v}^{(k_n)})^{\intercal}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
D =
\begin{pmatrix}
v^{(k_0)}_0 & v^{(k_0)}_1 &\ldots & v^{(k_0)}_N\\
v^{(k_1)}_0 & v^{(k_1)}_1 & \ldots & v^{(k_1)}_N\\
& &\ldots &\\
v^{(k_n)}_0 & v^{(k_n)}_1 & \ldots & v^{(k_n)}_N
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
so the vector $\vec{r}$ can be calculated by the following way
\begin{equation}
\vec{r} = D\vec{f}.
\end{equation}
The last equation corresponds to `np.dot( D, yl )` in the code.

It is also important to note that according to the Kotelnikov-Nyquist–Shannon theorem, there will be no loss of information only if (spectral density) the highest frequency of the useful signal is equal to half or less than the sampling frequency. Half of the sampling frequency is called the Nyquist frequency:

> `kmax= 1 / ( 2 * dl )`

Comment: Hi, just a tip on typesetting code: you can place them inside "backticks" which is this symbol $\to$ `  to get a monospaced font.

for example \`print( np.dot( D, yl ).round( decimals=9 ) )\` looks like `print( np.dot( D, yl ).round( decimals=9 ) )`

if you have multiple lines (but you don't in this answer), then you can instead indent each line by 4 spaces